# Selecting from multiple tables in Cassandra CQL

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql, cql3, cqlsh

So I have two tables in the query I am using:

```
SELECT
    R.dst_ap, B.name
FROM airports as A, airports as B, routes as R
WHERE R.src_ap = A.iata
AND R.dst_ap = B.iata;
```

However it is throwing the error:

```
mismatched input 'as' expecting EOF (..., B.name    FROM airports [as] A...)
```

Is there anyway I can do what I am attempting to do (which is how it works relationally) in Cassandra CQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer, is that **there are no joins in Cassandra**.  Period.  So using SQL-based JOIN syntax will yield an error similar to what you posted above.

The idea with Cassandra (or any distributed database) is to ensure that your queries can be served by a single node (cutting down on network time).  There really isn't a way to guarantee that data from different tables could be queried from a single node.  For this reason, distributed joins are typically seen as an anti-pattern.  To that end, Cassandra simply doesn't allow them.

In Cassandra you need to take a query-based modeling approach.  So you *could* solve this by building a table from your post-join result set, consisting of desired combinations of `dst_ap` and `name`.  You would have to find an appropriate way to partition this table, but ultimately you would want to build it based on A) the result set you expect to see and B) the properties you expect to filter on in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Is there a way I can build this result set from the data already in my tables?

Comment: @madcrazydrumma  Not intrinsically with Cassandra, no.  But you could probably write a Python script to query the tables, perform a client-side join, and then write it to Cassandra.